# Resampling pandas dataframe without datetime index in higher-dimensional bins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame with no datetime index. An example of my DataFrame is the following

```
    x1      x2      x3      y1      y2
0   0.83    0.83    1.16    0.0     1.0
1   0.83    0.83    1.25    0.0     1.0
2   0.64    0.85    1.09    0.0     1.0
3   0.72    0.94    1.06    0.0     1.0
4   0.73    0.85    4.04    0.0     1.0
5   0.83    0.94    4.84    0.0     1.0
6   0.56    0.43    1.07    0.0     1.0
7   0.59    0.56    1.05    0.0     1.0
8   0.59    0.91    2.05    0.0     1.0
9   0.59    0.96    4.99    0.0     1.0
10  0.83    0.56    7.99    0.0     1.0
```

I would like to resample this DataFrame by values of `x1,x2,x3` that lie in specific intervals and sum over `y1` and `y2`. Let's say that these intervals are `[0,1]` for `x1,x2` and `[1,8]` for `x3`. I divide these intervals with bins of width `0.01`. Then, I want to sum `y1` and `y2` for each value of `x1,x2,x3` in a given bin of these intervals.

How can I do this?

Comment: Will you please provide a sample output dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could round each of the `x` column values to their closest 0.05 decimals and use `groupby` + `sum`:

```
cols = ['x1','x2','x3']
out = df[cols].apply(lambda col: col.mul(10).astype(int).div(10).add(0.05)).combine_first(df).groupby(['x1','x2','x3'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
      x1    x2    x3   y1   y2
0   0.55  0.45  1.05  0.0  1.0
1   0.55  0.55  1.05  0.0  1.0
2   0.55  0.95  2.05  0.0  1.0
3   0.55  0.95  4.95  0.0  1.0
4   0.65  0.85  1.05  0.0  1.0
5   0.75  0.85  4.05  0.0  1.0
6   0.75  0.95  1.05  0.0  1.0
7   0.85  0.55  7.95  0.0  1.0
8   0.85  0.85  1.15  0.0  1.0
9   0.85  0.85  1.25  0.0  1.0
10  0.85  0.95  4.85  0.0  1.0
```